# Java to EXE good or bad idea?

Tags: java, windows, deployment, installation, exe

I have been wondering for a long time about converting **Java** projects to `EXE`.

The advantages relies in the faster deployment on **Windows** where the user simply double clicks the `EXE` and the application is launched where is with **Java**, he has to run certain commands.

But `EXE` is really not what the **Java** was intended for which is portability.

So what do you think, Java to EXE good or bad idea?

I found some interesting article [here](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html).

### Update

Wow, so may contradicting views so far. I would like you guys to add the pros and cons of the JAVA to EXE.

Comment: BAD! If you really like .exe, convert it to C# and compile it using Visual Studio.

If you put it in JAR file and properly author the manifest file, user can double click on the JAR file to launch the app (if they have JRE installed)

Comment: @Ken That's pretty hopeless advice. How about something constructive?

Comment: You can use .bat/.cmd file or jnlp. Or just executable jar. JNLPs do have bugs but overall are quite an ok solution for installation. All of these options do work w/ 'double-click'

Comment: 2nd thought: you'd need both 32bit and 64bit exe (+java) to make it look native, of course you can run just the 32bit, yet it's sort of uncool.

Comment: the question is what do you want to achieve, anyways see the updates in my post

Comment: @bestsss I would like to see an answer from you too :)

Comment: I have covered it pretty much in the comment. The easiest to deploy is via JNLP and this way you take care of automatic updates, a minus could be considered a bit slower starup and need for inet connection (can be wholly offline though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my expertise is with Java Web Start, which is for launching desktop apps. with a GUI, please consider my advice to be targeted mostly at those types of apps.

---

Other people have commented on the OS specific nature of an EXE.  I always have to wonder why people choose Java to develop Windows specific desktop apps., since the Visual Studio software for Windows would probably make both GUI development (no x-plat Java layouts to bend your head around) and deployment (just guessing it can produce an EXE) easier.

OTOH only you can say what is the best development tool/language for this use-case.

---

As to the potential disadvantages of creating an EXE, I note at the [JavaFAQ on EXEs](http://pscode.org/javafaq.html#exe).

There are a number of good reasons not to package your application in an executable. Daniel Sjöblom notes:

- It will probably not be any faster. Modern virtual machines don't interpret bytecodes, they actually employ a JIT compiler to produce native, compiled code. Check Sun's site for further information on JIT compilers.
- Static compilation increases the size of your application multifold, since all of the libraries you are using need to be linked into the application.
- You lose 'free' upgrades to your program. Anytime your user downloads a new faster virtual machine, your app gets a speed boost. If you are using an exe, you will not get this benefit.

Jon A. Cruz details some of the extra steps in the development process required to create an exe. He points out that developers making native exe's need to:

- Validate the latest versions of the compilation product from the vendor. If critical bugs are found, it can't be used to build a shipping product until those are addressed. Work that needs to be done each time a revision comes out from the vendor.
- Submit the software through a QA cycle. Once engineering thinks things are done, they need to be verified. So every shipping version and update of a product needs to go through complete testing cycles.
- Further, since native compilation is per target platform, the QA cycle needs to be done completely for each target platform, which multiplies effort required.
- Shelf space. Maybe not a big deal nowadays, but could be.
- Then one needs to get all customers to upgrade to the proper version. Either have free updates (in which case the business needs to absorb the cost of producing updates) or alternatively needs to handle clients not all updating.

Jon notes futher: When you ship standard Java bytecodes, VM problems are the responsibility of the platform or VM vendor. However, when you ship compiled binaries, they become your responsibility (even if they're actually bugs in the vendor's compilation product).

...

---

Of course, my first choice for deploying Java rich client apps. is using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Putting some of the benefits/features of web-start in point form:

JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to:

- splash screens
- desktop integration
- file associations
- **automatic update** (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates)
- partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version,
- configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.)
- easy management of common resources using extensions
  ..

---

I decided to highlight auto-update since with the gradual shift from apps. delivered on disk to apps. delivered over a network, auto-update is becoming more common.  JWS still provides the best update experience (very configurable, mostly transparent to the user) I've seen.

And of course, JWS works on OS' for desktop PCs for which Java is available.

---

### Update

> ..does Java web apps require internet connection?

(Note that name is 'Java Web Start'.)

Sure it does.  At least for the initial installation.  Update checks can be specified to continue to launch the previously installed version of the app. if the user is not currently connected.

But then, (in my estimation) there are more machines (such as Netbooks) with no CD/DVD drive, than there are without internet connections.  ***If you want to sell to the larger market, look to the network to deliver the app.***

Comment: Just one thing, I never used Java web before, but my question is does JAva web apps require internet connection?
Note:Visual studio is not for free when using for commercial uses.

Comment: See the update.  *"Visual studio is not for free when using for commercial uses."*  That is an *excellent* reason to develop using Java.  :)

Comment: *I always have to wonder why people choose Java to develop Windows specific desktop app* b/c they might have readily available libraries for java, actually they might want to run it on Mac later on (this is quite common), b/c they excel in java and time-to-market can be significantly shorter. there are a lot of other reasons.

Comment: @AndrewThompson if you look at the answer of Dmitry Leskov, how can I protect my code if I use for example Java Web Start?

Comment: Visual Studio Express **is** free for commercial use.

Comment: *"Static compilation increases the size of your application multifold, since all of the libraries you are using need to be linked into the application."* - Not true if you factor in the size of the JRE: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/java-download-size.html

Comment: *"how can I protect my code if I use for example Java Web Start?"*  How would you protect it otherwise?  See my comment on that answer, for my 'dripping with sarcasm' side-bar on obfuscation.  And 1) Don't fool yourself, nobody wants to steal your app. 2) Further, if they did, there are legal ways to do it without even looking at the code (most often).

Comment: It is not about "stealing the app", Andrew. Unfair use of C++ apps is just as common. And most of the code out there contains no unique IP. But the data accessed by that code can be way more valuable. Nearly all those multimillion IT failures of late were about data theft. Why not take an extra step to protect your or your clients' data?

Comment: *"Why not take an extra step to protect your or your clients' data?"* Sure thing, but make sure you spend your time/money on something likely to work.  Obfuscation won't.  The pundits suggest that a legal approach is more likely to be effective at protecting the investment in the software.  But then, this is really a separate question to 'JWS vs. EXE', since both can be decompiled/reverse engineered (albeit slightly easier with Java), I don't see any advantage either way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what that "legal approach" is all about. Suppose you discover that your StackExchange identity had been stolen and used to post offensive comments and stupid questions - who exactly would you sue and would you be able to achieve 100% recovery from such an incident?

Comment: @DmitryLeskov What has that got to do with software distribution?!?  Suppose you're cooking and your bread does not rise.  (It has about as much relevance!)

Comment: Scenario 1: Your fat client transmits user's credentials to some Web service. An intruder gets into the user's computer and wants to steal those credentials. Scenario 2: an intruder gets into your server and wants to figure out how your Web app stores sensitive data. In both cases you better make sure analyzing code would take the intruder enough time for you/user to detect the intrusion and take preventive measures. (Both scenarios of course assume that sensitive data is stored in some encrypted form, otherwise code analysis/tampering would not be needed.)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your needs. We had written a little barcode client scanner app here for our customer. They run it on two Windows-PCs. They are happy having their well-known exe-files. We coded it in Java and created an EXE-file for them.

Both parties are happy with it - so why not doing it?

When there are good reasons for it and nothing against it except dogmatism then it is ok in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the article you linked to - glad you've found it interesting!

As my article states, and as others have already pointed out in their answers, there are multiple ways to simplify deployment of Java apps - JNLP, EXE wrappers, installers bundling a private JRE, and so on. But true native compilation is the only option that also provides [protection against Java decompilers](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html) - you simply do not ship the bytecodes.

Of course, that does not make reverse engineering of and tampering with your code impossible, just much more costly in terms of required skillset and time.

As far as application performance is concerned, native compilation can make a **big** difference if you target embedded systems. This also applies to memory and disk footprint, albeit to a smaller extent. On the desktop you would typically get better startup, but in most other scenarios and aspects the results would depend on your app.

Comment: So you are saying that EXE is the safest way to protect your Java code, right?

Comment: No, I am not saying that, but in my opinion it is the most balanced way. I have linked to my other article discussing all four ways to protect Java bytecode that I know. The safest one has too many trade-offs to be recommended for general use.

Comment: *"protection against Java decompilers"*  <DWS>What, so you mean I need to get a *different* free decompiler for your damnable EXE?  I am so gonna' load this crack to a file share site, just for the inconvenience.</DWS>  About all that obfuscation is good for is reducing the file size of downloads.

Comment: BTW +1  for posting the best, most comprehensively argued alternate to the accepted answer.  I still do not agree with your analysis, but I am not about to presume that 'I am correct & you are wrong'.  It is interesting to see alternate views (that are well argued).  And as you say in the article *"there exist two completely different approaches to the creation of native executables from Java applications, addressing different sets of problems."*  Well put. :)

Comment: It's good to know that my question has started a rich debate between 2 armies :P

Answer (score 2):

If it has a good reason why not? Even Eclipse has an EXE on windows and (and platform dependent binaries for linux, mac, etc) Of course you loose portability but if that is not important then go ahead.

**UPDATE**

The question is what do you want to achieve by creating an exe :

- Convenience : users on windows prefer to click on icons, this is especially true for the non geeks. On the other hand non geeks don't care what the link does internally if it starts up an  exe or something else. You can have an application icon for non native Java applications too. The alternatives would be

  - Web start
  - Creating an installer package,e.g.: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html This can also solve the problem of installing the JRE
- Performance : If you compile your Java application into a native solution you may gain a bit on performance but it depends on what technology you use. For example Swing tends to be slow but compiling that to native is rather tricky. If you use SWT instead of Swing that is already using native components therefore no need for further native compilation. On the other hand recent JVMs perform very well and can compile java to native to further improve the performance bottlenecks. This is done silently on the background you dont need to worry about that.

Sum : in some cases it might be the only solution, but if you choose the right technologies there will be many Java based alternative solutions to reach the same goal.

Comment: w/ eclipse you lose portability from get-go since the SWT native libs, it's more understandable.

Comment: There is something confusing here. In your answer, you say **why not** but in your update, you say **it's not needed** and there are **other alternatives**.

Comment: ok it might be confusing, but true. Why not, it wont make any harm, but why yes as there are so many alternatives. Both in my original post and the update I say if you have a legitimate reason and find no alternatives then creating an exe file is acceptable. I just cannot think easily about a legitimate reason. But if you have share it and the community (or I) will try to figure out if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The page behind the link in the question is written by a company that sells products that compile java to native code. I would not base a decision on that alone.

The question also says that the advantage of the exe a better user experience, because the user can just double click to launch the application.

That *is possible* with executable jar file. In fact, its actually quite easy with standard tools in the java runtime. You just have to add a manifest to a jar file, and  specify the class with the main in it. You can also specify other jar files in the classpath relative to the location of the main jar file. You can also specify an image to use as a splash screen as a resource.

e.g.

```
Class-Path: lib/derby.jar lib/derbytools.jar lib/jcalendar-1.3.2.jar l
ib/joda-time-1.4.jar lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar lib/looks-2.2.1.jar lib/swi
ng-layout-1.0.jar
SplashScreen-Image: resources/splash.png
Main-Class: com.you.pkg.app.Main
```

The basic ant project in Netbeans will do all but the spash-screen for you if you use it. If your some reason you want to do all of that by hand, make sure you understand the format of the manifest file, its a bit finicky.

Comment: I am the author of that "page behind the link". It only gets to native compilation after discussing all the other options and linking to the respective tools.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. Just like there's nothing wrong with considering a possible bias in the source.

Answer (score 0):

As Linux, mac., Solaris user I think this is bad idea. 
If you want faster deploy on windows, just create installer.

Comment: but if you create an installer, you are only setting up the files, but how are you simulating the exe which is mainly accessing an application via double-click?

Comment: @abdmob he would need to provide a way to launch the program in different OS's, yes, but if anything he can provide a "pure" launchable jar version for them.

Comment: There is many multi platform installers. Usually they are using for desktop applications. You can create Windows shortcuts and user can just click or dbl click. Look for example free installer IzPack.

Answer (score 0):

Jar files provide many benefits including: 
Compact: The whole application (i.e. all the class files) is stored in one archive file (which can incorporate image and sound files if required).
Ease of use: The application can be run by double-clicking.
Compression: The jar format allows you to compress your files for efficient storage. 
Security: You can digitally sign the contents of a jar file. Users who recognise your signature can then optionally grant your software security privileges it wouldn't otherwise have.

I would not convert to exe.

Most Windows applications run from a .exe file (Word, Internet Explorer, FireFox, NetBeans, ...)
Java itself has no support for doing this as the executable file will then be platform dependent (i.e. it won’t run on Macs)
However, there are (free) applications that can do this for you.

Comment: You can also provide a JAR and a launcher executable. You don't have all these problems then.

Comment: Disadvantages of JAR:
Application will not start on systems that do not have a JRE (properly) installed

Application will not work if it uses APIs absent in the default JRE

Need to teach users that .JAR files are clickable

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft does it, so it must be a good idea!
All jokes aside, understand that it's not 'conversion' that you are looking for, but using a custom launcher. The article you linked does a nice job of explaining the different approaches and pros/cons of each. As a general idea, it requires the extra work of creating the launcher (and a different version for each different OS architecture), but it gives you a little more control (version checking is a nice feature, also you may update the application jar rather easily, like Minecraft does). Overall it's a good idea if you think it's worth the effort, and the (little) loss in portability.

Edit: the 'Custom Java Launchers And Wrappers' approach is the one that you should use if you don't need the really nifty extra features offered by those below it.

Comment: eclipse has it too, writing a small executable is to load jvm.dll and start process is a trivial task but not quite necessary. It's done so the application looks 'native'

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the user base. If they are tech-related in anyway then giving them a `.jar` file (which could be run by double click) is a good idea for mobility.

If your users are less techy but you still need it to run on multiple platforms then wrap it as `exe` for Windows and as `.app` for Mac.

**Important**: I would suggest making a script to wrap it into exe, so you run it each time you have a new version.

Comment: most exes just load jvm.dll and run the application, so new version do not affect 'em